# Unable to send data to another controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, controller

**UPDATE PLEASE HELP:**

Tried what you suggested, the problem is when i try to pass the value to another "Module". Tried creating a service but the function didn't work, maybe i missed something.
Made Example Using rootScope:

```
var informes = angular.module('informes', ['angular-drupal', 'ui.bootstrap']);

informes.controller('InformesCtrl', ['drupal', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'InformesFtry', function(drupal, $rootScope, $scope, $http, InformesFtry) {

       $rootScope.nodeID = function(item){
         var item = "hi";
         console.log(item);
       }

}]);
```

Console `hi`

It works in first module, but...

In my other Module with different Page...

```
var nodeInformes = angular.module('node-informes', ['informes']);

nodeInformes.controller('NodeInformesCtrl', ['drupal', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'InformesFtry', function(drupal, $rootScope, $scope, $http, InformesFtry) {

          $scope.nodeID2 = $rootScope.nodeID(item);
          console.log($scope.nodeID2);

}]);
```

Console: `item is Undefined`

I'm trying to figure out of how can i pass a function to another module, but it seems that it is impossible. I didn't try to use same module, but it works if the controller is child from the first controller.

I really apprecaite any help you can provide me to pass a function with parameter to another module with another controller. I'm trying to learn with this. Thanks!!!

EDIT: If i add the firstcontroller as a dependency it gives me Unknown Provider... Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular JS there are three ways for controllers to communicate with other controllers, and any other method is asking for trouble:

**Use a service:**

Use a service as an intermediary between controllers:

```
function MyService() {
  this.MyObject = {};
}

function ctrl1(MyService) {
  Myservice.MyObject = {
   someData: "someValue"
  };
}

function ctrl2(MyService) {
  $scope.someValue = MyService.MyObject.someData;
}
```

**Use the event system**

```
  function ctrl1($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$broadcast("my-event", {someData: "someValue"});
}

function ctrl2($scope) {
  $scope.$on("my-event", function(event, params) {
    $scope.someData = params.someData;
  });
}
```

**Scope inheritence**

```
 <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
   <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
   </div>
 </div>

function ctrl1($scope) {
  $scope.someData = "someValue";
}

function ctrl2($scope) {
  console.log($scope.$parent.someData); //"someValue"
}
```

Comment: It works when the module is the same... But i want to use another module.